# Is there a way to groupby in polars while keeping other columns?

Tags: python, python-polars

I am currently trying to achieve a polars groupby while keeping other columns than the ones in the `groupby` function.

Here is an example of an input data frame that I have.

```
┌─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ SRC ┆ TGT ┆ IT  ┆ Cd  │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ f64 │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 1   ┆ 1   ┆ 2   ┆ 3.0 │
│ 2   ┆ 1   ┆ 2   ┆ 4.0 │
│ 3   ┆ 1   ┆ 2   ┆ 3.0 │
│ 3   ┆ 2   ┆ 1   ┆ 8.0 │
└─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┘
```

I want to groupby `['TGT', 'IT']` using `min('Cd')`, which is the following code :

`df.groupby(['TGT', 'IT']).agg(pl.col('Cd').min())`

With this code line, I obtain the following dataframe.

```
┌─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ TGT ┆ IT  ┆ Cd  │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ f64 │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 1   ┆ 2   ┆ 3.0 │
│ 2   ┆ 1   ┆ 8.0 │
└─────┴─────┴─────┘
```

And here is the dataframe I would rather want

```
┌─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ SRC ┆ TGT ┆ IT  ┆ Cd  │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ f64 │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 1   ┆ 1   ┆ 2   ┆ 3.0 │
│ 3   ┆ 2   ┆ 1   ┆ 8.0 │
└─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┘
```

I thing I could achieve this by joining the first dataframe on the grouped one using `['TGT', 'IT', 'Cd']`, and then delete the doubled rows, as I only want one (and any) `'SRC'` for each `('TGT', 'IT')` couple. But I wanted to know if there is a more straightforward way to do it, especially by keeping the `'SRC'` column during the `groupby`

Thanks by advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import polars as pl

# Your data
data = {
    "SRC": [1, 2, 3, 3],
    "TGT": [1, 1, 1, 2],
    "IT": [2, 2, 2, 1],
    "Cd": [3.0, 4.0, 3.0, 8.0]
}

df = pl.DataFrame(data)

# Sort dataframe by 'Cd'
df_sorted = df.sort('Cd')

# Perform the groupby and aggregation
result = (
    df_sorted.groupby(['TGT', 'IT'])
    .agg(
        [
            pl.col('SRC').first().alias('SRC'),
            pl.col('Cd').min().alias('Cd')
        ]
    )
    .select(['SRC', 'TGT', 'IT', 'Cd'])  # to reorder columns
)

print(result)
```

[image]

Comment: This seems to work perfectly ! I juste have a question, is the ```alias()``` function necessary ? In my case the columns do not seem to be renamed, but maybe there exists cases where it can happen ?

Comment: alias wouldn't be necessary in this case. It's necessary when your output has multiple transformations of the same input column as you can't have multiple columns with the same name.

Comment: @Haeden I just assumed that you may need it to change to the real column names